# Spring jpa send "SET SESSION TIME ZONE UTC" on every database session

Tags: spring, postgresql, timezone, spring-boot

I have this Postgresql database that serves many applications.

I'ts configured like this:

```
log_timezone = 'Mexico/General'
timezone = 'Mexico/General'
```

A Spring boot (1.2.5.RELEASE) application now needs to store it's timestamps in UTC.

Since I can't change the database default, what I guess I would need to do is to execute `SET SESSION TIME ZONE UTC;` at the beginning of each database session.

I thought of using data.sql. but it's only run once at startup, right?
Later on, when the database connection pool grows or shrinks, it wouldn't be executed again, right?

I'm using HicariCP for the DB connection pooling. (`com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.2.5`)

Does anybody knows how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can change that for the user: `alter user foobar set timezone = 'UTC';` then you don't need to configure Spring at all

Comment: You can set it per-session by configuring the ``connectionInitSql`` with the string "SESSION TIME ZONE UTC".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wow, didn't know that option exist. It's not [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-alterrole.html) (or I couldn't find it)

Comment: @brettw Yes... that also is a great solution. Don't know why it didn't think about that before. Thanks.

Comment: It is documented - `SET configuration_parameter = ..` and further down the explanation for  `configuration_parameter`

Comment: You're right, later on it refers to the [set documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-set.html) sorry. :)